# QPython - Reading a file

Tags: android, python, qpython

I have installed QPython in my Android mobile.
I written a statement in the QEdit to read a text file from the below path

`/storage/emulated/0/com.hipipal.qpyplus/script3/File1.txt`

I used the below statement

```
fob=open('/storage/emulated/0/com.hipipal.qpyplus/script3/File1.txt','r')
fob.read()
```

If I run the statement, it is throwing error as:

```
IOError:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/storage/emulated/0/com.hipipal.qpyplus/script3/File1.txt'
1|uo_a116@cancro:/ $
```

Is the above statement correct?

Comment: That code works for me, just make sure that your keyboard produces normal single quotes: ' ' instead of ‘ ’.

Answer (score 3):

```
fob=open('File1.txt','r')
```

Is not working in version 1.0.4.

```
fout=open('File2.txt','w')
```

Was working on version 0.9.6, but is not working in 1.0.4.
The "error" is Read only file system.

It looks like restrictions in the (new 1.0.4) file system library. I post a mail to the editor, but no answer at this time.

Answer (score 1):

For testing, try to write absolute path to your files pointing, for example, to sdcard (/sdcard/out.txt).
I had problems on this versions (>=1.0.4) because launch process of script changes and execution directory is not the same as script directory.
I had to change my scripts to point to absolute paths.
It was tested with qpython developer.

Check this link:

https://github.com/qpython-android/qpython.org/issues/48

Answer (score 0):

You can also try as simple as:

```
fob=open('File1.txt','r')
fob.read()
```

Just if the script is in the same folder of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the current working directory to path with script before read file:

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```